# Custom Python GTK+3 CellRenderer for TextBuffer

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to write a custom Python GTK+3 CellRenderer that extends CellRendererText to display the contents of a TextBuffer stored within a ListStore, but can't wrap my head around how to extend the CellRendererText class to do this. Ideally, it'd look something like this:

```
liststore = Gtk.ListStore(object)
textbuffer= Gtk.TextBuffer()
liststore.append([textbuffer])

renderer_text_buffer = CellRendererTextBuffer()
column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text_buffer, text=0)

treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
treeview.append_column(column_text)
```

So essentially would be a very simple TextView inside a TreeView cell. Not worried about any of the rich text features of TextView at the moment, I just want to be able to grab the plain text out of a buffer stored in a ListStore and display it in a TreeView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well, I have to say that CellRendererText is quite so ineffective when there is too many characters in it (like over 100 characters).

Comment: I'm not too worried it displaying the complete contents of the TextBuffer, so truncating it to less than 100 characters would be fine. I'm just trying to get a representation of what is in the buffer. When the user clicks on the row in the TreeView it will load into a full TextView for editing.

Comment: Oh, that's easy.

Bind a callback function to selection event of treeview. That function is used to do these things:

    (1) create a dialog window, which contains a textview(with a textbuffer) and one or two buttons;

    (2) set content of textbuffer with content of current selected cell.

    (3) after used edited and that dialog closed, save content of that textbuffer back to current selected cell.